# Chart.js ignore options

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a line chart with chart.js but when I try to style my chart.
Everything from options is ignored.

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let ChartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      layout: { padding: { top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 12 } },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Cubic interpolation mode'
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{ gridLines: { color: '#22364e', borderDash: [9, 7] } }],
        yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false } }]
      },
      plugins: { datalabels: { display: false } },
      legend: { display: false },
      elements: {
          point: { radius: 5 },
          line: { tension: 0.4, fill: false },
      },
      //tooltips: {},
      hover: { mode: 'nearest', animationDuration: 400 },
    };
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Fri", "Sun", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#6ebffe',
            pointBackgroundColor: '#6ebffe',
            pointBorderColor: '#8cff00',
            data: [320, 325, 300, 350, 340],
          }
        ],
        options: ChartOptions
      }
    });
</script>
```

I tried to copy the code from https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/interpolation-modes.html but it's the same. I can't add options to my chart.
Even the title is not showing. This is not a cache problem because I run it with chrome devtools open and tried with a different browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the options are in the wrong place,
they should be placed after the `data` object

```
  data: {
  },
  options: ChartOptions
```

you had them as part of the data object...

```
  data: {
    options: ChartOptions
  },
```

see following working snippet...

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let ChartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      layout: { padding: { top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 12 } },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Cubic interpolation mode'
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{ gridLines: { color: '#22364e', borderDash: [9, 7] } }],
        yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false } }]
      },
      plugins: { datalabels: { display: false } },
      legend: { display: false },
      elements: {
          point: { radius: 5 },
          line: { tension: 0.4, fill: false },
      },
      //tooltips: {},
      hover: { mode: 'nearest', animationDuration: 400 },
    };
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Fri", "Sun", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#6ebffe',
            pointBackgroundColor: '#6ebffe',
            pointBorderColor: '#8cff00',
            data: [320, 325, 300, 350, 340],
          }
        ]
      },
      options: ChartOptions
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes thank you it worked. Tried for hours and it was just a short inattention