# Chartjs Options are ignored

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to use a simple [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) chart on my site, but all options are ignored. So, my questions seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606451/chart-js-ignore-options), but as far as I can tell, I have the options in the right place.

So, here is the (very simple) code:

**JS**

```
let config01 = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: [
        'Part 01',
        'Part 02',
        'Part 03'
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [2000, 1000, 600],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(0, 76, 138)',
            'rgb(50, 151, 230)',
            'rgb(250, 202, 55)',
          ],
          hoverOffset: 10
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        color: '#000000',
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
        }
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "linear"
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Some Title',
        fontColor: 'rgb(0, 18, 58)',
        fontSize: '18',
        padding: 5
      }
    }
  };
  
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart-01').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config01);
```

**HTML**

```
 <body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart-01" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
  </div>
 </body>
```

And here would be a working (without the options being applied) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SunnyRed/n45k71v6/6/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined at each docs part for that specific thing (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options) you can see the namespace, in which you can see that the title and legend have to be configurated in the plugins section since they are internal plugins, this is also stated in the migration docs (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Live working example:

```js
let config01 = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      'Part 01',
      'Part 02',
      'Part 03'
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [2000, 1000, 600],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(0, 76, 138)',
        'rgb(50, 151, 230)',
        'rgb(250, 202, 55)',
      ],
      hoverOffset: 10
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        color: '#000000',
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Some Title',
        font: {
          color: 'rgb(0, 18, 58)',
          size: 5
        },
      }
    },

    animation: {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "linear"
    },

  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart-01').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config01);
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart-01" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha, looks like we were racing each other for the answer. Have an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

`legend` and `title` are meant to be in `options.plugins`:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      color: '#000000',
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Some Title',
      fontColor: 'rgb(0, 18, 58)',
      padding: 5,
      font: {
        size: '18'
      }
    }
  },
  animation: {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "linear"
  }
}
```

Comment: your title options are incorrect, the font options have changed in v3 https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/fonts.html